# How do i write a function counting crosses in an image?

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm writing a function that is going to go through images and count the number of green crosses present. Under here is a sample image. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JGAh.jpg)

I'll convert the image to a numpy asarray where 128 is the number representing the green in the crosses, in each cross there is at least 2 pixels of green in each direction from the center.

We have this general skeleton for the code to work within:

```
def numberOfCrosses(M):
    
    cross = 0
    
    for i in:
        for j in:
            
    return cross
```

Could someone point me in the right direction on where to start with this?

Comment: I am not sure that this "general skeleton" be very helpful. Give us your ideas.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please look over [the Stack Overflow guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) on asking & answering homework questions.  The TL;DR is that the question needs to show some work to answer the question on its own, and that the answerers shouldn't give you a complete answer to the whole question, but should instead try to lead you to the right answer.

So, in an attempt to do that:

- What imports / packages are you likely to need? Which data types and functions from those packages are familiar and useful? Can you find reference pages or tutorials for the less-familiar pieces? Update the list as you go through the next few steps.
- What is the type of the original image file? How do you intend to convert it to a numpy array?
- How do you plan to identify a *single* green cross?  Write a function
  for this which, given a position in the matrix, can tell you whether
  or not there's a cross at that single position.
- What do you think you should be looping over?  You've been given two loop variables in the starter code.
- Assuming you have a function which tells you whether or not there's a cross at *one* position, how would you scan the full image and accumulate the results for the number of positions which are found to have green crosses?
- Once you have the answers to those, how do you want to output the answer? Do you want to report the positions or just the total number? Are you writing to a file? to the screen?
- What sorts of assumptions did you make in answering all the above? Can you generate your own test cases? How does your code handle situations when there are *no* crosses? When the crosses are the wrong color? When crosses overlap? When the input image is *entirely* the target color?